# Can not add additional tags using the new GUI Builder 5.6

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying the use the new GUI Builder to create tabs.  I know that you can hand code the component, which I did for the main one. But I do have many additional which the new GUI builder could help.

I was able to create a new tab with two default tabs already added. I could modify it. It seems to work.  But I cannot add additional tabs. It worked in the old GUI builder.

Can someone help?  I'm using the codenameone 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced this myself, tabs are pretty flaky under the new GUI builder. This is something we need to address but probably isn't trivial to fix. Can you please file an issue in the project: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new
so we can keep track of this.

Comment: I just filed an issue on this. Hope we can fix it soon